# SWC-126 Insuffixient Gas Griefing attack: why not simply requiring a successfull sub-call?

Tags: security, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to learn more about the SWC Smart Contract Weakness Classification and Test Cases. I'm stuck on understanding SWC-126: https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-126. Especially, I don't understand the proposed solution in the link and how it fixes the attack vector?

Wouldn't this attack vector simply be a sub-case of https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-104? We could simply require the call to be successfull after line 26 of the relayer.sol contract by writing:

`require(success)`

So that the complete transaction reverts in the case that the remaining gas isn't sufficient to execute the sub-call?

Also, I don't understand how the proposed solution in relayer_fixed.sol would fix our problem, since it would only revert the sub-call and the relayer contract would continue without evaluating the pre-vented sub-call?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inserting require(success); line would definitively work.

Second, that solution actually works because the revert() statement just reverts the entire transaction to its initial state. In that way, if there is not enough gas to complete the transaction, instead of just "skipping" it, it would revert the entire transaction.

Hope this is useful :)